# Calculate average in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, pivot

My table is like this

```
C1   Bool    Count

A    TRUE     5
A    FALSE    5
B    FALSE    6
C    TRUE     2
C    FALSE    8
```

I want to calculate the portion of count in Bool=True, group by C1. The ideal result should be

```
C1   Portion
A      0.5
B       0
C      0.2
```

I am not really sure how to achieve this. Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select c1, sum(case when bool then count else 0 end) / sum(count) ratio
from mytable
group by c1
```

This assumes that `bool` is of `bool[ean]` datatype, so it can be used directly in a condition predicate.

Note that both `bool` and `count` are language keywords in MySQL, hence poor choices for column names (the above query would error if you were to run it as it is).